# plot can't show in DolphinDB GUI

Tags: plot, dolphindb

```
x = 0.1*(1..100)
y = 0.1*(100..1)
t = table(x,y)
plot(t)
```

This is the code I wrote but the function `plot` failed and cannot show in DolphinDB GUI. Only a table is returned in the data browser. How to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

The default *chartType* of function `plot` is "LINE".

You must set extras: {multiYAxes: } to true to support multiple Y-axis.
The corrected code is

```
x = 0.1*(1..100)
y = 0.1*(100..1)
t = table(x,y)
plot(t, extras={multiYAxes: true} )
```